# How to set max width of a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitoolbar

I have a UIBarButtonItem in a UIToolbar that is updated with changes to a title represented by a text field.  The text field should not have a short maximum length.  When the title is quite long, the item occludes the button items to its right.  How can I make it automatically truncate to a certain width?
[image: Interface Builder]
[image: Simulator]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a custom view with maximum possible width, `textAlignment` set to `UITextAlignmentCenter` and `lineBreakMode` to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`.

```
UILabel* l = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)]autorelease];
//200 is just a number I choose. you should calculate your maximum possible value
l.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
l.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
self.navigationItem.titleView = l;
```

Comment: It looks like Helvetica 20.0 Bold matches the default.

Comment: `UILabel* l = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)]autorelease];
    //200 is just a number I choose. You should calculate your maximum possible value
    l.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    l.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    l.minimumFontSize = 10;
    l.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];// if you need the bold version [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = l;`

:)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the width in the Storyboard Size Inspector:

[image]